# Push to database and increment integer key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm using Firebase Realtime database as my backend, and I have a problem, that probably has a really simple solution..

I want to push some information to the database, but as things stand, instead of pushing a *new* object, it is simply updating the db..

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
   firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/entries/'+$scope.todos.id+'/trackers/'+$scope.currTrack.id).update({
        note: individual.note,
        value: individual.value
    });
```

So it's pretty straight forward, but this is what's happening in the db:

```
...
   -KuB-l8OX9zxGYuGw_EK //this is $scope.currTrack.id
      note: "the note",
      value: "the value"
```

so instead of creating a new incrementing integer key it just puts it right under the id..

What I *would* like to happen is:

```
...
   -KuB-l8OX9zxGYuGw_EK //this is $scope.currTrack.id
      0 //incrementing integer key
         note: "the note",
         value: "the value"
      1
         note: "the 2nd note",
         value: "the 2nd value"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using `update` but `set` works the same as well..

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using update but set works the same as well..

From [firebase.google.com Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data):

> Ways to Save Data
>
> **set**    Write or replace data to a defined path, like messages/users/
>
> **update** Update some of the keys for a defined path without replacing all of the data

I think you need to use `push` API:

> **push**   Add to a list of data in the database. Every time you push a new node onto a list, your database generates a unique key, like messages/users//

Comment: I've tried `set`.. it had the exact same effect... it just updates the variables but it doesn't create a new item with an integer key

Comment: @JaneDoe updated answer , did you try to use `push`?

Comment: that sort of works, it does create a new key for each, but it's not an integer.. it's a randomly generated key.. which is fine I suppose

Comment: just curious, do you know a way to do it with just an integer key instead of unique key?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code , Every time you do update() ,the array on

> 'users/' + uid + '/entries/'+$scope.todos.id+'/trackers/'+$scope.currTrack.id

is reset with the new value i.e. it clears the data on firebase first and the adds a new entry into it.
If you want what you said then you can achieve it by

- retrieving all the array elements first using once() and save it to an array , say **list**
- push your item to **list**
- then perform an update()

But then it does not make any sense.

### Another way

Maintain a **count** variable.

```
var count = 0;

...update({
    [count++]: {
      note: individual.note,
      value: individual.value
    }
  });
```

---

But would recommend you to either use post() or structure your firebase db as this [link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) says.